# Moving Yii controller action into cron job

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cron

I am using this [site](http://mintao.com/3-easy-steps-to-create-and-execute-cronjobs-with-yii) as a guideline to set up a cron job in yii.

My current controller action in TableA (update) will execute a sql transaction to populate TableB in my db when I change a given value (Value2) from "A" to "B".

Here is the code I currently use to accomplish this.  This is in my update action in controller A

```
$connection = yii::app()->db;
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO TableB (value1, value2, value3)
     VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3)";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);
$command->bindValue(":val1", $model->tableAId);
$command->bindValue(":val2", 'B');
$command->bindValue(":val3", $model->Attribute2);
$command->execute();
```

Since I am using bindValue it is easy to get my values to input into the different table.  Moving this logic into a cron job I do not know where to start to execute the same things.

So will this work the same using similar code in the cron job?

```
public function run($args)
{
    $transactions = TableA::model()
    ->findBySql('SELECT * FROM `TableA` '.
    'WHERE `value2` = A '.
    'AND TO_DAYS(`DateCreated`)+3 < TO_DAYS(NOW())');
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        $connection = yii::app()->db;
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO tableB (value1, value2, value3)
             VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3)";
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);
        $command->bindValue(":val1", $model->tableAId);
        $command->bindValue(":val2", 'B');
        $command->bindValue(":val3", $model->Attribute2);
        $command->execute();
    }
}
```

I need to create a new record in TableB but also update value2 in TableA from "A" to "B"

I have already tried running this cron job but not getting any results and not sure how to go about troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use TableA and TableB model?

in Controller A:

```
$model = $this->loadModel();
$model->value2 = 'B';
if ($model->save()) {
   $modelB = new TableB();
   $modelB->value1 = $model->value1;
   $modelB->value2 = $model->value2;
   $modelB->value3 = $model->value3;
   $modelB->save();
}
```

in cron job

```
// find all
$transactions = TableA::model()->findAll(array('condition' => array(
  'value2 = :A',
  new CDbExpression('TO_DAYS(`DateCreated`)+3 < TO_DAYS(NOW())'),
), 'params' => array( ':A' => 'A')));
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    $model->value2 = 'B';
    if ($model->save()) {
        $modelB = new TableB();
        $modelB->value1 = $model->value1;
        $modelB->value2 = $model->value2;
        $modelB->value3 = $model->value3;
        $modelB->save();
    }
}
```

or also you can create function in modelA:

```
public function createB()
{
    $modelB = new TableB();
    $modelB->value1 = $model->value1;
    $modelB->value2 = $model->value2;
    $modelB->value3 = $model->value3;
    $modelB->save();
}
```

And call it when you need